# Image cropping problems (IDE :- Android Studio (Java))

Tags: android, bitmapimage

I went through many links and checked various codes for this but it doesn't fit my requirement yet.

Here is my requirement;

1. I want to select image either from phone memory or sd card (give option to user to select image directory) and crop it.

Problem in it, in lollipop OS, when I select image from gallery it does not provide cropping option hence getData returns null but if I select image from Photos it crops the image and save it hence getData returns the URI but the original image gets overwritten with this cropped one.

2. In Jellybean the situation is reverse, if I select image from gallery everything works fine but from Photos, cropping option does not come.

Below is the code snippet..

```
public void selectImageFromGallery() 
{
        try
        {
            Globals g = (Globals) getApplication();
            int iWidthDP = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, g.screenWidth, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int iHeightDP = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", iWidthDP);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", iHeightDP);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "exception occurred in selectImageFromGallery" +
                    ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        try
        {
            if ((requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY || requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA)
                    && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    Uri selectedImage = null;
                    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY || requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
                        selectedImage = data.getData();
                        if(selectedImage == null)
                            selectedImage = (Uri)data.getExtras().get("data");
                    }
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
                    {
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor;
                        try {
                            parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedImage, "r");
                            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
                            parcelFileDescriptor.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "exception occurred in onActivityResult" + ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "exception occurred in onActivityResult" + ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }


                    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "exception occurred in onActivityResult" + ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: do you want crop image when you select image from galleray or camera ?

Comment: From both but let's now focus on Gallery first.

Comment: i suggest you to use library for this it is easy

Comment: Can you suggest which librry to use or give me the link, i'll check.

Comment: check my answer @Gvs13

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use library for this. here is step for setup :

first add this in your build.gradle module:app

this is in android section:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'http://lorenzo.villani.me/android-cropimage/'
        }
    }
```

this is in dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.1'
        compile 'me.villani.lorenzo.android:android-cropimage:1.1.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

for pick image from camera

```
 EasyImage.openCamera(Context, 0);
```

for pick image from gallery

```
EasyImage.openGallery(Context, 1);
```

after this.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode,  int resultCode,  final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        EasyImage.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, this, new DefaultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onImagePickerError(Exception e, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {
                //Some error handling
            }

            @Override
            public void onImagePicked(File imageFile, EasyImage.ImageSource source, int type) {

               // Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageFile).into(imageView);

                    Uri uri = null;
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                    file = imageFile;
                    CropImageIntentBuilder builder = new CropImageIntentBuilder(200, 200, uri);
                    builder.setOutlineColor(0xFF03A9F4);
                    builder.setSourceImage(uri); //data.getData()

                    startActivityForResult(builder.getIntent(MainActivity.this),100);
            }

        });

        if ((requestCode == 100) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
            // When we are done cropping, display it in the ImageView.
           // imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(file).into(imageView);

        }

    }
```

Dont forget to add this in your android Android.manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.android.camera.CropImage"/>
```

this will help you to get image from gallery and camera with crop functionality it is reduce your code and easy to maintain for pick image.

Hoe this will help you

Comment: dont forget to Declare one variable "File file" at global and change "imageView" is your imageview.

Comment: Can you share the lib file locations from where I can download it.

compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.1'
compile 'me.villani.lorenzo.android:android-cropimage:1.1.+'

Comment: you need to just add those line in your build.gradle in depandences @Gvs13

Comment: After adding those lines it says cannot resolve reference for both of them.

Comment: sorry for mistack i forgot to add something related library can you please check my updated answer @Gvs13

Comment: you also need to add "repositories" for compile library so just add also those line.@Gvs13

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105778/discussion-between-gvs13-and-rushabh042).